# Handling queries with both master and slaves/primary and secondaries in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to scale reads with MongoDB. To do this i can setup master-slave replication or replica set, but if I create connection to Mongo like this:

```
from pymongo import ReplicaSetConnection, ReadPreference
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure

try:
    connection = ReplicaSetConnection("somehost:10000", replicaSet='myapp_repl',
                                  read_preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY) 
except ConnectionFailure ...
```

or:

```
from pymongo.master_slave_connection import MasterSlaveConnection
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure

try:
    master = Connection(host="somehost", port=10000)
    slave1 = Connection(host="somehost", port=10001)
    slave2 = Connection(host="somehost", port=10002)
    connection = MasterSlaveConnection(master, slaves=[slave1, slave2])
except ConnectionFailure ...
```

**pymongo** driver will distribute queries among replica set secondaries/slaves. In this situation primary/master will not handle queries, so if I'll have 2 nodes I will not enhance reading capabilities, because only 1 node will handle queries. How can I make both master and slaves (primary and secondaries) handle queries?

Comment: No idea if this will work but what happens if you try: 

`connection=MasterSlaveConnection(master, slaves=[slave1, slave2, master)`

?

Comment: Hmm, its actually works! Is there any solution for replica set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but:

```
connection = MasterSlaveConnection(master, slaves=[slave1, slave2, master)
```

MasterSlaveConnection is deprecated though.

I am not sure of any other way of fixing this.

You might want to look into sharding or adding an arbiter to vote in new primaries: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Adding+an+Arbiter

Comment: ReadPreference is already SECONDARY, but this option doesn't force pymongo to balance queries between primary and secondaries(only between secondaries, if they exists).

Comment: So after asking around in #mongodb I couldn't figure out a way around this :/, I can tell you that it will fall back to the primary if the secondary nodes are down.

Comment: The discussion above is correct; in the near future we'll probably add ReadPreference.ANY to PyMongo to allow distribution among all members of a replica set.